# How to convert a ruby array output into a string in JS?

Tags: javascript, string, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this line coming from a helper in the BE and I want to set a variable with that output. No matter what I tried (toString, string interpolation etc) It keeps returning me the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined at eval (eval...
```

This is my code:

```
document.myStr = <%= get_str %>
```

This is the result:

```
document.myStr = a,b,c;
```

Answer (score 0):

All [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) need to be enclosed with two square brackets, `[` and `]`.

Plus, it looks like you are writing in `a`, and the interpreter sees the token `a` (which is assumed to be a variable's name) and it looks for a variable named `a`.

Since you do not seem to have declared `a` already, it throws an error as `a` is now `undefined`.

What you can do is declare `a` earlier or enclose it within quotes, like `'a'` or `"a"`.